# How to pass a value from one form to a private TextBox in another Form via a pubic static class?

Tags: c#, class, constructor, static, public

I have an `Invoice form` with several private TextBoxes. I want to pass some values from my DataGridView in `search form` to those TextBoxes in `Invoice form`(when I press Enter for example).
What I want to do is to pass the values of the current selected row in the DataGridView to be passed to certain TextBoxes in `Invoice Form`:
I could illustrate this in the following code:
(I know how to get the values of selected row in datagridview my question is just the title...)

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM X WHERE ID=" +
                        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value + "", sqlcon);
    SqlDataReader sqldr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (sqldr.Read())
    {
        InvoiceForm.CodeTextBox = sqldr[codecolumn].Tostring
        InvoiceForm.NameTextBox = sqldr[Namecolumn].Tostring
        InvoiceForm.BlahTextBox = sqldr[Blahcolumn].Tostring                               
    }
}
```

which throws the following error at me:

> codeTextBox is private... not able to do so because of protection
>   level...

I think I have to make a public static class to do so, but I dont know how.
How I tried:

```
 private string RetrivedCode;
        private string RetrivedName;
        private int RetrivedQTY;
        ...

    Public Form1(string CodeTextBox , string NameTextBox, string BlahTextBox)
    {
      this.CodeTextBox= RetrivedCode; 
      this.NameTextBox= RetrivedName; 
      ... and so On 
    }
```

which errors:

> cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to
>   'system.windows.forms.textbox'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to change the access level of your `CodeTextBox` to public inside the **InvoiceForm** which is called **InvoiceForm.Designer.cs** file.

Comment: what a good point. what word should I look for in InvoiceForm.Designer.cs?

Comment: CodeTextBox i think that is the attribute name of your TextBox

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error is quite clear, you're trying to `convert type 'string' to 'system.windows.forms.textbox'.`

```
while (sqldr.Read())
{
    //textbox                  string
    InvoiceForm.CodeTextBox = sqldr[codecolumn].Tostring();
    InvoiceForm.NameTextBox = sqldr[Namecolumn].Tostring();
    InvoiceForm.BlahTextBox = sqldr[Blahcolumn].Tostring();
}
```

if you instead set the `text` property on the textbox, the error goes away.

```
while (sqldr.Read())
{
    // Note the ´Text´ property.
    InvoiceForm.CodeTextBox.Text = sqldr[codecolumn].Tostring();
    InvoiceForm.NameTextBox.Text = sqldr[Namecolumn].Tostring();
    InvoiceForm.BlahTextBox.Text = sqldr[Blahcolumn].Tostring();
}
```

UPDATE:

The same thing really, even if it's the second part that is the part that is throwing errors. I assume `CodeTextBox` is a text box?

```
this.CodeTextBox.Text = RetrivedCode; 
this.NameTextBox.Text = RetrivedName;
```

But you're asking the wrong question. Because you don't have to "make a public static class to do so". If you make your textboxes protected (if your second form inherits the first form) or public instead of private, you'll be able to assign the value directly in accordance with my first examples.

If your text box neccessarily has to be private, use a public or protected accessor or a public method that sets the value of the Text property of the Text boxes.

Comment: you completely got my question wrong... . the error you talked about is for my second code block not for my frist code block.

Comment: See edit: The error is still clear and the solution the same. But the question you're asking is probably not the one you need answered.

Comment: @absolute455 are you having any progress? Did you try to set you textboxes to public according to my edit and then set the text property?